# Using verb after class of [plural]

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I have the following sentence:

> These files are often vulnerable to a class of viruses known as xx
>   viruses which targets their structure format.

The word `targets` refers to the `class of viruses`. What is the right verb in this case: target or targets?

Comment: Do you understand whether "a class of viruses" is singular or plural?

Comment: That's the confusing point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "class" in this sense isn't a collective noun:

> **class**: a group into which animals, plants, etc. that have similar characteristics are divided, below a phylum

Source: [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/class_1)

And considering the subject-verb agreement, "targets" is the only choice.